# Play sound clips programmatically from html5 canvas in iOS?

Tags: ios, html5-canvas, html5-video, html5-audio

I'm hoping it's possible to make interactive presentations that play sounds on certain user events using the canvas, *and* have it work properly and load on iOS, either as a mobile site, phonegap type thing, or wrapped webview. I know html5 and video is a total dead end on iOS (stupid) because of the no-autoplay and no gobble all clicks issue. If I'm not using video but just moving pictures around (think "Ken Burns effect" with buttons too), and I want some short audio clips to play when a button is clicked, is this going to work on iOS or are there crazy no-autoplay-no-preload restrictions that prevent that too? Any pointers to working examples would be fine too, the signal-to-noise ratio on searching this question is abysmal. ;-)

Comment: The same restrictions apply to both video and audio on iOS. You have to get direct physical interaction from the user to begin playing or preloading either.

Answer (score 0):

For playing audio on iOS and android you have to use html5 audio tag .

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="yourFile.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

this comes with inbuilt control . If you want custom look and fill then there are some libraries in jquery ,you can use that .